# AngularJS - setting selected value of dropdown does not work

Tags: angularjs, select, set, selecteditem, ng-options

I made a fiddle replicating my problem here: http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/2840/

As the title suggests, I can't set the selected value of a select populated using ng-options.

I have searched and tried all possible solutions that I found. Any help or suggestions would be appreciated!

HTML

```
<div ng-app>
    <h2>Todo</h2>
    <div ng-controller="TodoCtrl">
        <select ng-model="ddlRooms" ng-options="r.id as r.Name for r in Rooms">
        </select>
        {{$scope.test}}
    </div>
</div>
```

Angular

```
function TodoCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.Rooms = [{ Name: 'Toddler', id: 1 },{ Name: 'other', id: 2 }];
    $scope.options = [{ Name: 'other', id: 2 }];
    $scope.ddlRooms = $scope.options[0];

    $scope.test = 'bla';
}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Because you are doing `id as name` you need to assign id to the model:

```
$scope.ddlRooms = $scope.options[0].id;
```

Comment: That did it! Thank you very much! Any insights as to why? I'm assuming its because Angular binds to the value..

Comment: How to solve it if my select tag is like:  <select ng-model="formA.ddlRooms" ng-options="r.id as r.Name for r in Rooms">

Answer (score 6):

better to do:

```
<select ng-model="ddlRooms.id" ng-options="r.id as r.Name for r in Rooms">
```